# Problem Loading UPWORK

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, ssl

I am using 64-Bit Ubuntu 15.10, and trying to install **upwork** time tracking app for last 5 hours,I was able to install the upwork app but now it's saying `THERE WAS A PROBLEM LOADING UPWORK Please check your internet connection and restart the app.` I am unable to find the problem. Upwork App log is

```
[0429/000545:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/000545:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/000547:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/000936:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/000936:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/000937:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/001521:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001521:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001522:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/001635:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001635:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001637:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/001804:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001804:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/001806:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/002043:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/002043:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/002044:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/003120:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/003120:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/003121:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1528)] X error received: serial 61, error_code 3 (BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)), request_code 4, minor_code 0 (X_DestroyWindow)
[0429/003121:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/003141:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/003141:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/003142:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
[0429/121920:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/121920:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0429/121923:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(359)] Unknown SSL error -12218 mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Please tell me what is the problem with upwork and how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the answer and positing here so that this ans could out help other dev like me.

`For Ubuntu 15.10 (32 bit)`

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r libnss3
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-1d_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnss3-1d_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb libnss3-nssdb_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

`For Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit)`

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r libnss3
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb libnss3-nssdb_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

To prevent libnss update, no more error after ubuntu update:

`sudo apt-mark hold libnss3 libnss3-nssdb`

Hope this will work out for everyone.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot! This works on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: Indeed, Ubuntu 16.04. Saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: This. You just saved my butt.

Comment: One question - is it correct that to re-enable autoupdates (once Upwork fixes it), I need to run:

`sudo apt-mark unhold libnss3 libnss3-nssdb`

?
That said - worked for me (Ubuntu MATE 14.04), thanks a lot!

Comment: Didn't work for me. Getting this error: http://pastebin.com/Biqzr02R

Comment: But this is a wrong solution. Instead of upwork coming out with solution compatiable with Ubuntu you are downgrading yours. Not a good advice for Ubuntu users. Should not mess with Ubuntu OS like this. Other unknown problems could creep up in your Ubuntu, who knows.