# Problem loading Upwork in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ssl

I am using 64-Bit Ubuntu 16.04, and trying to install Upwork time tracking app. I was able to install the Upwork app but now it's saying: `THERE WAS A PROBLEM LOADING UPWORK Please check your internet connection and restart the app`.

Note: This question is only for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

Answer for Ubuntu 15.10 is here - [Problem Loading UPWORK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764780/problem-loading-upwork)

Answer (score 0):

As I found an answer at [Upwork Community Forum](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Error-Message-THERE-WAS-A-PROBLEM-LOADING-UPWORK/td-p/83016/page/18) posted by [Dmitriy K](https://community.upwork.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/76388) :

> *In ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus (should work also on debian-based*
>   *systems).*
>
> *Issue resolved by downgrading libnss3 package to 3.19. This can be*
>   *done by entering these commands.*

Unhold previously holded packages:

```
apt-mark unhold libnss3 libnss3-nssdb
```

**(for 64 bit)**

```
mkdir -p /tmp/libnss-tmp
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/
libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_amd64.deb
dpkg -x /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_amd64.deb /tmp/libnss-tmp
sudo cp -rf /tmp/libnss-tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /usr/share/upwork
rm /tmp/libnss-tmp -rf
```

**(for 32 bit)**

```
mkdir -p /tmp/libnss-tmp
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss
/libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb -O /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_i386.deb
dpkg -x /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_i386.deb /tmp/libnss-tmp
sudo cp -rf /tmp/libnss-tmp/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/* /usr/share/upwork
rm /tmp/libnss-tmp -rf
```

**The answer for Ubuntu 15.10 is here - [Problem Loading UPWORK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764780/problem-loading-upwork)**

Comment: Almost worked for me. 

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/ downloads only index.html file, so I downloaded libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb manually from another place.

Not sure what libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb -O /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_amd64.deb is supposed to do but from the next commands I suppose something like mv  libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb /tmp/libnss-tmp/libnss3_amd64.deb so I did the latter.